# Use WinInet::InternetSetOption() always returns false and GetLastError() returns 12018

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, wininet

I want to let the ie's IWebBrowser didn't need to select the certificate, so I use `InternetSetOption()` to do that. The code is:

```
HCERTSTORE hMyStore = CertOpenSystemStore(0, _T("MY");
PCCERT_CONTEXT pDesiredCert = NULL;
pDesiredCert=CertFindCertificateInStore( 
    hMyStore, 
    X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
    CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR,
    L"cnstr",
    NULL);

if (InternetSetOption (NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, 
        (LPVOID)pDesiredCert, sizeof(CERT_CONTEXT)) == FALSE) { 
    DOWRD i = GetLastError(); 
} 
...
```

I get the certificate in the "MY" store. When I use `InternetSetOption()` to set the certificate, it return false, the error code is 12018. I searched some infomation about this error code:

> "12018  ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_TYPE The type of handle supplied is incorrect for this operation."

I want to set the global setting, so I set NULL to the first parameter, does the first parameter in the function `InternetSetOption()` couldn't be `NULL`?  And how could I set the option correctly?

Comment: Why c# is tagged? What language is this? If c++ remove c# from tag

Comment: Sorry, because I think C# use the some api. I have removed that.

Comment: You can't use a NULL handle and IE doesn't expose the HINTERNET handle it uses.  That spells doom to this approach of course.  Get ahead by googling "install certificates for internet explorer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already told, you can not use `NULL` for `INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT` option. Although, some option can possess`NULL` value, such as `INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_RETRIES` or `INTERNET_OPTION_DATA_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT`, it can't.

[Option Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328(v=vs.85).aspx)

You have to use a valid `HINTERNET` by using `InternetOpen()` or `InternetConnect()`.
Below link will guide you for valid `HINTERNET` on 'Scope of HINTERNET Handle' section.

[Setting and Retrieving Internet Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385384(v=vs.85).aspx)

And, you have to check `hMyStore` and `pDesiredCert` values whether those are `NULL`, also.

**EDIT : **

You can not get `HINTERNET` by using `IWebBrowser2`. It just exposes methods and property of `WebBrowser` control. So, you have to use `InternetConnect()`.

> For example, client applications that require a proxy with authentication, probably do not require setting the proxy user name and password every time the application attempts to access an Internet resource. If all requests on a given connection are handled by the same proxy, setting the proxy user name and password on a connection type HINTERNET handle, that is, a handle created by a call to InternetConnect, would allow any calls derived from this HINTERNET handle to use the same proxy user name and password. Setting the proxy user name and password every time an HINTERNET handle is created by HttpOpenRequest would require extra and unnecessary overhead. Be aware that if the application uses a proxy that requires authentication, it should set the proxy credentials on every new connection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385384(v=vs.85).aspx

I also wrote some useful reference link about how to use `InternetConnect()`.

[C++ WinHTTP InternetReadFile not retrieving entire source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278401/c-winhttp-internetreadfile-not-retrieving-entire-source)

[SSL with WinHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464860/ssl-with-winhttp)

Comment: Thanks, it help me! I can get the IWebBrowser2 control, how could I do in this situation?

Comment: @lvshuchengyin I've edited my answer. I hope this will help you a little. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: InternetConnect() didn't work. Only HttpOpenRequest's HINTERNET could be set INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT, but it can affect the IWebBrowser2. But Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I solved this problem by calling all these functions: InternetOpen(); InternetConnect(); HttpOpenRequest(); InternetSetOption();InternetReadFile(); Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the applied answer is correct. Though there exists another problem, which reveals itself in a similar manner.
You can get error "INCORRECT_HANDLE_TYPE", if the constant `INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT` is incorrectly defined. In this case you just will be passing the wrong option. The right value is `84` (dec) in WinInet

```
#define INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT 84
```

the corresponding constant in WinHttp should be

```
#define WINHTTP_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT 47
```

Do not mix them. Be cautious and have a good time coding!